# Run python script on startup and wait for keyboard input

Tags: boot, python-3

I know, I know, it looks like the 1000th question about the same thing, but I have tried almost every answer I came across here about running scripts on startup, but they fail to meet my particular use case. So let me describe what I actually want to do first:

I have written a Python program (PantrySentry) that lets me scan a bar code of a product, looks up the name in a database, and puts it on a Google Keep list with my pantry items.

The program works just fine and the bar code scanner interfaces with it like a keyboard, i.e., the scanned code is translated to numbers and passed to the python script just as if I had typed it in. So the user interface of the script is basically just a command line input, waiting for a number and a return.

And that is the problem: I learned on this website how to run a script on startup to completion (not applicable, because the script contains an infinite loop waiting for another item), how to run it in the background (not applicable, because it needs user interaction), how to run it via SSH (also not applicable, because the local keyboard/barcode scanner input is necessary.

Essentially, all I want to do, is automate the steps I take when I start the script myself:

(Log in via VNC)

1. Open a terminal
2. cd Projects/PantrySentry
3. "python PantrySentry.py"
4. Let the script process the local keyboard input forever.

My question is: how?

Any help or pointer to the right previously asked question would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the down vote for? I explicitly mentioned that I am aware of the fact that this *looks* like a question already answered elsewhere, but that none of the solutions I found after thoroughly searching helped.

If I missed something and it has been answered already, I would appreciate a pointer in the right direction instead of just a silent downvote.

Comment: Could you link the tutorials you tried to use as a comment?

Answer (score 1):

Two methods you could use:

#### Cron

You can edit the crontab by typing this in the terminal: `crontab -e`. Then you should add this line to the bottom `@reboot python Projects/PantrySentry/PantrySentry.py`.
Read the Cron docs here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md

#### Systemd

I have never used Systemd before but this is how it should work.
Type `sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/PantrySentryStarter.service`. Add this to the file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start the PantrySentry Program
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python Projects/PantrySentry/PantrySentry.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enter:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable PantrySentryStarter.service
```

Read the systemd docs here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md

After you're done with one of these reboot to check if it's working.

Comment: You linked to a very bad example to use systemd. And I cannot see any reason to use `Type=idle`. Can you please explain why to use it?

Comment: @Ingo I have mentioned in the answer that I have no experience using systemd, which is why I placed it second. It was in this tutorial: https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/10/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-boot-using-systemd/, it was the first result to my query. The explanation on the website: The “Type” is set to “idle” ensures the ExecStart command is only run when everything else has loaded. For my GPIO based scripts, the default type of “simple” didn’t work.

Comment: These are the solutions I find everywhere, but it just does not work for me. I tried the crontab way as recommended and nothing happened. I tried using ```@reboot lxterminal --command "python Projects/PantrySentry/PantrySentry.py"``` and nothing happened either.  I guess, I am going to try my luck on the Linux stack exchange

Comment: @Simon If you don't have any luck there you could try reinstalling the OS on the Pi.